# VARCHAR to DATE format in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a VARCHAR data type in a order_date column which contains dates, I would like to convert it to DATE format except for null values. How can I solve this?

Comment: `select '2022-09-24'::date; 09/24/2022` where `select pg_typeof('2022-09-24'::date); date`. `select null::date; null`.

Comment: What can I do if I want to select the whole column of the order_date except for null values for my table?

Comment: `select order_date::date from some_table where order_date IS NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

Where is an problem?

```
(2022-09-24 17:48:11) postgres=# select to_date('2022-07-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
┌────────────┐
│  to_date   │
╞════════════╡
│ 2022-07-08 │
└────────────┘
(1 row)

(2022-09-24 17:48:42) postgres=# select to_date(null, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
┌─────────┐
│ to_date │
╞═════════╡
│ ∅       │
└─────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: What if I want to select the whole column not just instead of one date?

Comment: @Chris - then you can write `FROM table` clause. Maybe is can be good time to start read some about SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need use
`TO_DATE(column_name,'YYYYMMDD')`

Specify the format of the date in the varchar field the way it is as second input parameter to the `TO_DATE` function

and
apply filter
 `where column_name is not null`

You can refer to this [documentation](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-to_date/) for further reference.

Comment: It has an error indicating that: column column_name does not exist when I tried your format

Comment: column_name is a place holder, you need to give the name of the column name that you have in your table.

Answer (score 0):

> The PostgreSQL formatting functions provide a powerful set of tools
> for converting various data types.

You should use them!

**Here is the link to the related doc:** https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html

The above depends on your Postgres version. However, `to_date(text, text)` must work.